# Django "list_filter" based on the admin queryset

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application which has both admins and sub-admins. Sub-admins are created based on the group they belong to. So a sub-admin can see only data which is related to his group. This functionality is working perfectly.

Now, I want to create a filter option based on users. For super-admin it works fine but when I see from sub-admin, I can see the complete list of users in the filter list. How can I limit this list based on sub-admins users.

Suppose there is a total of 20 users, and sub-admin has only 3 users in his group. So I am able to see only 3 in the list view but in the filter option I can see all 20. Can I limit this filter to only those 3 users only?

My admin model looks like below:

```
class VideoDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('video_id', 'user', 'status', 'description', 'video_name', 'upload_time', 'duration')

    list_filter = ('user', )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Get the groups of logged in user
        query_set = Group.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        group_list = []
        for g in query_set:
            group_list.append(g.name)
        # Get the user ids of Users in those groups
        id_list = []
        for user in list(User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=group_list)):
            id_list.append(user.id)
        # Create unique users list
        users = list(set(id_list))
        # Override the get_queryset method for Admin
        qs = super(VideoDetailsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(user__in = users)
        else:
            return qs
```

I've seen few resources available on Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), but I am wondering what could be the best approach to solve this problem. Is there a way I can re-use the get_queryset() code

**Django Version: 2.1**

**EDIT 1:**

Made following modifications but no filter is visible.

```
# Filter list
class UserFilterList(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # Human readable title, which is displayed on the right sidebar
    title = ("User")

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query
    parameter_name = "user"

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        # To get user's groups
        query_set = Group.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        group_list = []
        for g in query_set:
            group_list.append(g.name)
        # To get all users associated in those groups
        id_list = []
        for user in list(User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=group_list)):
            id_list.append(user.id)

        users = list(set(id_list))
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(user__in = users)
        else:
            return qs
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
class UserFilterList(SimpleListFilter):
    title = "user"
    parameter_name = "user"
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        visible_users = model_admin.get_visible_users(request)
        print(visible_users[0])
        return ((user, user) for user in visible_users)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return self.value()
```

**FINAL WORKING SOLUTION (THANKS TO @dirkgroten):**

```
class UserFilterList(SimpleListFilter):
    title = "user"
    parameter_name = "user"
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            visible_users = model_admin.get_visible_users(request)
            # Sub user - return same group users
            return ((user.id, user) for user in visible_users)
        else:
            # Superuser - return all users
            return ((user.id, user) for user in User.objects.filter())

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(user=self.value()) if self.value() else queryset

class VideoDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('video_id', 'user', 'status', 'description', 'video_name', 'upload_time', 'duration')

    list_filter = (UserFilterList, )

    def get_visible_users(self, request):
        # Get the groups of logged in user
        query_set = Group.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        group_list = []
        for g in query_set:
            group_list.append(g.name)
        return User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=group_list)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        users = self.get_visible_users(request)

        # Override the get_queryset method for Admin
        qs = super(VideoDetailsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(user__in = users)
        else:
            return qs
```

Comment: As shown in the documentation you linked to, you need to create your own list filter by subclassing `SimpleListFilter`. The two methods are quite self-explaining, just return a different list to `lookups` depending on whether the user is admin or sub-admin. Especially the green Note further down should be helpful. So you should try first, then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: how are you plan to distinguish those three user?

Comment: Based on the common group. That' I've already achieved in above mentioned code piece

Comment: @dirkgroten following is my understanding from that code piece - it will work on the getting results based on the customized filter, in that case its 80s, 90s etc. But what I am actually looking for is to limit the elements in the sidebar itself and django should used it's logic to retrieve the results. Suppose for Admin there are 20 users in the sidebar, I want sub-admin to see only 3 users. These 3 users will be determined based on the user's group similarity with this sub-admin

Comment: No, `lookups()` is returning the choices shown in the list filter. So you should return the 3 users you want to show. They are tuples (value, display), in your case it's the (`id`, `name`). Then `queryset()` is the query to return based on the selected value but in your case it's just the default so you probably don't need to override it.

Comment: please see the updated code, just made few changes

Comment: that code was working for your default list view, it has almost nothing to do with the code you need for `lookups`  in your filter (so you should keep your original code as is, not replace it). This code now doesn't make any sense. `lookups` needs to return something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change your `VideoDetailsAdmin`, only use a custom list filter:

```
class VideoDetailsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = UserFilterList  # that's the only line to change

    def get_visible_users(self, request):  # small refactor to re-use in filter
        query_set = Group.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        group_list = []
        for g in query_set:
            group_list.append(g.name)
        # To get all users associated in those groups
        return User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=group_list)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        users = self.get_visible_users(request)
        # Override the get_queryset method for Admin
        qs = super(VideoDetailsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(user__in=users)
        else:
            return qs

class UserFilterList(SimpleListFilter):
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        visible_users = model_admin.get_visible_users(request)
        return ((user.pk, user.username) for user in visible_users)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.value()) if self.value() else queryset
```

Comment: I need to do few modifications like adding def queryset() without that it wasn't allowed. Though I am looking for usernames but now I can see the user id's but nothing is happening when I click on that. Please check EDIT 2

Comment: Now it links are working but by default it is showing nothing, and if I click on "ALL" it shows nothing. Though it works fine when I click on individual user IDs

Comment: then the values I put in the tuple are probably the wrong way, or the the wrong type is posted. check your browser source code to see the values in the links and set a breakpoint inside `def queryset()` to check what `self.value()` is.

Comment: yeah, self.value() is empty for 'all'

Comment: Default self.value() is None, but when I select individual elements it is the value of those elements like 44, 26 etc.

Comment: Perfect, it is working now. One last thing is I am still getting user ID instead of name. Also, I cannot use user.pk as it gives me - 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'. By anyway can we get usernames?

Comment: that's because the list was returning user ids, not users. I've changed the code to deal with a list of users now. Just not knowing your models, you might have to check `get_queryset` works correctly, is `user` attribute on `Video` a ForeignKey or an int?

Comment: `user` is a foreign key in the `Video`