# Django admin list_filter: RelatedFieldListFilter based on user

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

The question is similar to [Django "list_filter" based on the admin queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574344/django-list-filter-based-on-the-admin-queryset). I need to use list_filter based on current user. But in my case the field span relations using the __ lookup. There is no useful "lookups" method on RelatedFieldListFilter. My approach resulted in the next code:

```
def custom_titled_filter(title):
    class Wrapper(admin.FieldListFilter):
        def __new__(cls, field, request, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = admin.FieldListFilter.create(field, request, *args, **kwargs)
            instance.title = title

            rel_model = field.remote_field.model
            qs = rel_model._default_manager.all()
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
                qs = qs.filter(user=request.user)
            choice_func = operator.attrgetter(
                field.remote_field.get_related_field().attname
                if hasattr(field.remote_field, 'get_related_field')
                else 'pk'
            )
            instance.lookup_choices = [
                (choice_func(x), str(x)) for x in qs
            ]
            return instance

    return Wrapper
```

Is there any better approach with current version of Django?

Comment: Or should I just create a custom SimpleListFilter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136544/4316976)

Comment: Yes, you can create a custom list filter and according to the current user, you can change the filters.

Comment: @AkashJoshi I know I can. The point is I still need to implement lookup choices the same way and even create a filter class for each field or convert string to lookup expression. Is there a better way in current Django?